# Anyway to compress HTML output with Martini?

Tags: go, martini

In a quasi-embedded environment so speed is everything. I have found that if I compress my .html files, the app is speedier. Is there a flag or way in Martini to do this on the fly?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `gzip` Middleware

https://github.com/codegangsta/martini-contrib/tree/master/gzip

```
import (
  "github.com/codegangsta/martini"
  "github.com/codegangsta/martini-contrib/gzip"
)

func main() {
  m := martini.Classic()
  // gzip every request
  m.Use(gzip.All())
  m.Run()
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This answer is just to show that @fabrizioM's answer actually works:

#### Step 1: Create the server

```
package main

import (
        "github.com/codegangsta/martini"
        "github.com/codegangsta/martini-contrib/gzip"
)

func main() {
        m := martini.Classic()
        // gzip every request
        m.Use(gzip.All())
        m.Get("/hello", func() string {
                return "Hello, World!"
        })
        m.Run()
}
```

#### Step 2: Run the server

```
go run main.go
```

#### Step 3: Try the server

This is the step where you must remember to include the `Accept-Encoding: gzip` header (or equivalent).

Without compression:

```
curl --dump-header http://localhost:3000/hello
```

> ```
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> Date: Wed, 09 Jul 2014 17:19:35 GMT
> Content-Length: 13
> Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
>
> Hello, World!
> ```

With compression:

```
curl --dump-header http://localhost:3000/hello -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip'
```

> ```
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> Content-Encoding: gzip
> Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
> Vary: Accept-Encoding
> Date: Wed, 09 Jul 2014 17:21:02 GMT
> Content-Length: 37
>
> �       n��Q��J
> ```

Comment: `curl --dump-header - http://localhost:3000/hello -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip'` if you get 'curl: no URL specified!' error.